# How to return stdout and stderr together with the status from a Jenkins Pipeline sh script step

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, stdout, stderr

The answers to this question were inspired by [@codeGeass'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6688182/codegeass) comment to an answer to [*How to execute a command in a Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline job and then return the stdout*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39042591/1744774):

> Can we use them together ? catch returnStdout in a variable and returnStatus in an other ? because it is not cool to repeat the sh script twice

Comment: A [solution was provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32129323/598141) to a similar question, but just for shell cmd, outside of Jenkins.

Comment: @IanW Thanks for the info. I think that the OP's demand "_Filter stderr_" there complicates things...and...as you say, it's without Jenkins.

Comment: Nope. Should I?

Comment: I stopped wondering why some Q get downvotedd and closed almost instantly, while others which clearly should be downvoted and closed or just deleted (the homework type, no research, helpdesk, etc.) never seems to be. Maybe change wording to not say self-answered, instead, in an extension to this Q, added scenario ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To return `stdout` and `stderr` together with the status you can do the following:

```groovy
def runScript(command) {
    script {
        sh script: "set +x ; $command 2>&1 && echo \"status:\$?\" || echo \"status:\$?\" ; exit 0", returnStdout: true
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('more values from sh') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // inline
                    def stdoutAndStatus = sh script: 'set +x ; ls -a 2>&1 && echo "status:$?" || echo "status:$?" ; exit 0', returnStdout: true
                    echo "stdoutAndStatus: >$stdoutAndStatus<".trim()
                    
                    def stderrAndStatus = sh script: 'set +x ; ls notexisting 2>&1 && echo "status:$?" || echo "status:$?" ; exit 0', returnStdout: true
                    echo "stderrAndStatus: >$stderrAndStatus<".trim()
                    
                    // with function
                    echo "runScript: >${runScript('ls -a')}<".trim()
                    echo "runScript: >${runScript('ls notexisting')}<".trim()
                    
                    // failing the sh step
                    echo "runScript: >${runScript('not_existing_command')}<".trim()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Console Output

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (more values from sh)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ set +x
[Pipeline] echo
stdoutAndStatus: >.
..
status:0
<
[Pipeline] sh
+ set +x
[Pipeline] echo
stderrAndStatus: >ls: notexisting: No such file or directory
status:2
<
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ set +x
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
runScript: >.
..
status:0
<
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ set +x
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
runScript: >ls: notexisting: No such file or directory
status:2
<
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ set +x
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
runScript: >C:/Users/jenkins/AppData/Local/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/SO-36956977 more values from sh@tmp/durable-af2cee22/script.sh: line 1: not_existing_command: command not found
status:127
<
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However the shell script step doesn't display the whole CLI command, but only the first part: `+ set +x`. Do you know if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: @Boris See [Bash's `set`](https://ss64.com/bash/set.html): "_Using + rather than - will cause the option to be turned off._".

Answer (score 2):

There's an open issue for this feature since 2017...
[Allow sh to return exit status, stdout and stderr all at once](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44930).
Until it is done, you can create your own function to execute shell, and receive **both stdout and exit code**:

```
def runCommand(String cmd) {
    def stdout
    def rc = 0
    try {
        stdout = sh(script: cmd, returnStdout: true)
        echo stdout
    } catch (e) {
        echo "${e}"
        rc = "${e}".tokenize().last()
    }
    return [stdout, rc]
}
```

For example, calling it in pipeline steps script:

```
def (out, rc) = runCommand("echo hi ; bad command ; echo there")
echo "RC = ${rc}"
echo "OUT = ${out}"
```

Will output:

```
+ echo hi
+ bad command
/home/jenkins/workspace/nmanos/debug@tmp/script.sh: line 1: bad: command not found
hi
[Pipeline] echo
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 127
[Pipeline] echo
RC = 127
[Pipeline] echo
OUT = null
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain (Windows *Git*) *Bash* it works as follows (inspired by [@Ian W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598141/ian-w)'s comment to the question above):

#### `stdErrAndOutAndStatus.sh`

```bash
stdErrAndOutAndStatus () {
    $1 2>&1 ; echo "status:$?"
}

stdOutAndStatus=$( stdErrAndOutAndStatus 'ls -a' )
echo -e "$stdOutAndStatus\n"
stdErrAndStatus=$( stdErrAndOutAndStatus 'ls notexisting' )
echo -e "$stdErrAndStatus\n"
stdErrAndStatus=$( stdErrAndOutAndStatus 'not_existing_command' )
echo -e "$stdErrAndStatus\n"
```

#### Output

```bash
$ ./stdErrAndOutAndStatus.sh
.
..
stdErrAndOutAndStatus.sh
status:0

ls: cannot access 'notexisting': No such file or directory
status:2

./stdErrAndOutAndStatus.sh: line 3: not_existing_command: command not found
status:127
```

NB: I hope there's no pitfall of/in Bash I'm not aware of (yet). I don't write scripts too often.